# Locking console when computer suspends/hibernates

Tags: console, suspend, hibernate, lock, pm-utils

In X I've used the following script ([from here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pm-utils#Locking_the_screen_saver_on_hibernate_or_suspend)) to lock the computer with i3lock each time `pm-suspend` or `pm-hibernate` are invoked.

/etc/pm/sleep.d/00screensaver-lock:

```
#!/bin/sh
 # 00screensaver-lock: lock workstation on hibernate or suspend

 username=andreas
 userhome=/home/$username
 export XAUTHORITY="$userhome/.Xauthority"
 export DISPLAY=":0"

  case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend)
       su $username -c "/usr/bin/i3lock & 
       ;;
    thaw|resume)
       ;;
    *) exit $NA
       ;;
  esac
```

Now I'm in the process of setting up a console-only laptop (a minimal Debian install without the X server installed.)

I've tried using the above script on that machine to lock my session using vlock. (That is: I've switched out `i3lock` with `vlock` in the version of the script I'm using on the console machine.) I've also tried commenting out the two lines starting with `export XAUTHORITY` and `export DISPLAY=":0"` as they are X specific.

The script doesn't work on the no-X machine.

How should I call vlock each time the computer suspends/hibernates?

Comment: There are several scripts on that page you refer to, help us out by telling us what you have done (which script), paste it into your question, which you can [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/118384/edit), and explain what you mean by `console-only` since this sort of implies not using X a gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple script does the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend)
       /usr/bin/vlock -ans &
       ;;
    thaw|resume)
       ;;
    *) exit $NA
       ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you for this, very useful. You can also export USER to have vlock ask for a user password instead of root's: `USER=me /usr/bin/vlock -ans &`